crear linea visual basic para ocultar mas de un commandbutton a la vez
estoy usando esta programacion para ocultar un commandbutton en el visual basic de excel, pero me da error si repito la programación para ocultar otro, y no se tampoco si puedo incluir los dos botones en la misma programación:
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Address = "$P$2" Then
   With ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects("CommandButton8")
        If [P2] < 2 Then .Visible = True Else .Visible = False
    
   End With

End If

End Sub

quiero ocultar el 8 y el 9 a la vez, por ejemplo.
Si no es posible, metería otra programacion adicional, pero tampoco me está funcionando, oculta el primer boton, pero no el segundo.
Soy novato en esto y me está constando.
Muchas Gracias.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Si se pueden incluir los dos botones en la misma funcion. si copias el with y le apuntas al otro boton no funciona?

Si están los 2 botones en la misma hoja no debería darte error. Si cada botón está en hojas diferentes, cada hoja tiene su propio evento Change y tendrás que meterlo ahí. En cualquier caso, ¿qué error te da?

prueba lo siguiente:
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Target.Address = "$P$2" Then
        With ActiveSheet
            ' Controlar la visibilidad del primer botón
            .DrawingObjects("CommandButton8").Visible = [P2] < 2
            
            ' Controlar la visibilidad del segundo botón
            .DrawingObjects("CommandButton9").Visible = [P2] < 2
        End With
    End If
End Sub

